# pingouin rm_corr for repeated measure ordinal data in python?

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, ordinal-data

I have a similar situation to this question:

[Repeated measure correlation in Python](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408003/repeated-measure-correlation-in-python)

Where I have repeated measures from participants since they fill out a questionnaire each day. I can use pingouin's rm_corr to get the correlation between two of the questions in the questionnaire, but my understanding is that this is analogous to a pearson's test, but adjusted for repeated measures. Since my data is ordinal (5-point likert scale), I would use spearman if I did not have repeated measures.

Question: I don't see a version of rm_corr that explicitly extends spearman to repeated measures. Is it nonetheless OK to use as-is?

If it is not OK due to my ordinal data, can I manually do the ranking of my data, then use rm_corr, to essentially get a repeated measures spearman test?

Thanks for any assistance!